# 'http://www.domain.con/Image.jpg' is not a valid virtual path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In `subdomain.domainname`, I have a generic handler which is supposed to load images from the `domainname`

```
Dim Path As String = "http://www.domainname/"
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
context.Response.WriteFile(Path & ImgName & ".jpg")
```

The problem is that i cannot add a physical path, since the Responce.WriteFile accepts a physical path. And i get that valid virtual path error.

So how can i load images when images exist in `domainname` and my generic handler is at `subdomain.domainname`?

Is there any trick, i could use?

I do not want to move the handler to the `domainname`

Comment: You can always put the path to the domainame images directly in the config and do your WriteFile. It's a better solution that redirecting every image asset on the site on every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just redirect the request to the non-subdomain?

```
context.Response.Redirect(Path & ImgName & ".jpg")
```

Comment: @Maras I do not now how the shell this one works, but it sure does! Could you point a interesting link, regarding such info? Thanks!

Comment: All this does is send a response to the browser requesting the image, telling the browser to, instead of retrieving the image from the subdomain, to retrieve the image from the path passed to `Response.Redirect`.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could download the image first and then write the buffer to the response:

```
Using client = New WebClient()
    ' This assumes that http://www.domainname.com/ returns a JPEG image
    Dim file As Byte() = client.DownloadData("http://www.domainname.com/")
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
    Dim filename = Path.ChangeExtension(imgFile, "jpg")
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & filename);
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing out the obvious here, but aren't you missing the top-level domain, i.e. `.com`?

`http://www.mydomain.com/`